# Web UI framework without JavaScript

Tags: css, user-interface, frameworks

I'm a programmer at heart. I am not great at UI development and it takes 90% of my time.

I'm wondering if there is a UI framework which uses only CSS and no JavaScript. I found http://www.gantry-framework.org but it seems to be targeted at Joomla and Wordpress.

Any suggestions will be very welcome. It will help me with my development.

Thanks.

***ADDITION***

I'm looking for a framework that allows me to easily design and deploy a user interface for my website. Something that reduces the time it takes to make them manually.

I'm not looking to make effects or other special stuff like modal windows etc. (I use Qooxdoo and jQuery UI for advanced UI). Just basic layout and nice looks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Advanced UI development without Javascript is... complicated, to say the least; many things become hellishly complex, or outright impossible. You should add more detail about what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are CSS frameworks available to use, if that's what you're interested in:

1. [960 Grid](http://960.gs/)
2. [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html)
3. [BlueprintCSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)

Comment: i saw 960 grid. do you have any experience with it? how good will you say it is?

Comment: I don't use CSS frameworks, but those I know that do mostly use 960 and like it.

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://purecss.io/. It's a Yahoo project.